# Number of subsets with a given sum . Recursion not tracing few branches of the tree

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization, subset-sum

I have written this code in python and it is not yielding the right answer for the input wt[]=[2,3,5,6,8,10] in this order . It is giving right answer for few other combinations like wt[]=[3,2,6,10,8,5].I I have also tried tracing the recursive tree to debug accordingly but still cannot figure out why the code is not tracing some branches of the tree.
Kindly please help me figure out the problem.
Thank you!

```
n=6      #int(input())
m=10     #int(input())
wt=[2,3,5,6,8,10]
dp_table=[[-1 for i in range(n+1)]for j in range (m+1)]
total=[0]
def SS(m,n):
    a=0
    b=0
    if m==0:
        print(n-1)
        total[0]=total[0]+1 
        return 0;
    if n==0:
        return 0;
    else:
        if wt[n-1]>m:
            return (SS(m,n-1));
        else:
            if dp_table[m-wt[n-1]][n-1]==-1:
                a=SS(m-wt[n-1],n-1) + wt[n-1]
            if dp_table[m][n-1]==-1:
                b=SS(m,n-1)
            dp_table[m][n]=max(a,b)
               
        return dp_table[m][n];
if m==0 or n==0:
    print("Not Possible!")          
if SS(m,n)==m:
    print("Possible and the no of subsets with equal sum are: ",total[0])
else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: What is the expected output for `[2,3,5,6,8,10]`? It would also help if you used more descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing results in `dp_table` but never using them (giving incorrect results). If the dp_table value of an entry isn't `-1`, you're ignoring the result (and assuming it's always 0).

Often it's better to do the cache-checks at the top of the function (or better yet, use [functools.cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html)).

If you really want to keep the code structured as it is now, this will fix the issue:

```py
def SS(m, n):
    a = dp_table[m - wt[n - 1]][n - 1]
    b = dp_table[m][n - 1]
    if m == 0:
        total[0] += 1
        return 0
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        if wt[n - 1] > m:
            dp_table[m][n] = b if b != -1 else SS(m, n - 1)
        else:
            if a == -1:
                a = SS(m - wt[n - 1], n - 1)
            a += wt[n - 1]
            if b == -1:
                b = SS(m, n - 1)
            dp_table[m][n] = max(a, b)

        return dp_table[m][n]
```

If you want to do the caching yourself, you can put cache checks at the top (a better approach), rather than putting a check (and an if-else statement) before every recursive call, like this:

```py
def SS2(m, n):
    if dp_table[m][n] != -1:
        return dp_table[m][n]
    if m == 0:
        total[0] += 1
        dp_table[m][n] = 0
    elif n == 0:
        dp_table[m][n] = 0
    else:
        if wt[n - 1] > m:
            dp_table[m][n] = SS(m, n - 1)
        else:
            dp_table[m][n] = max(SS(m - wt[n - 1], n - 1) + wt[n - 1], SS(m, n - 1))

    return dp_table[m][n]
```

But the most 'Pythonic' and least work alternative is to use the decorators built into the standard library. You can limit the total memory usage, and it might even be faster if your manual DP-table happens to have cache-unfriendly access patterns.

```py
import functools

@functools.cache
def SS3(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        total[0] += 1
        return 0
    elif n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        if wt[n - 1] > m:
            return SS(m, n - 1)
        else:
            return max(SS(m - wt[n - 1], n - 1) + wt[n - 1], SS(m, n - 1))
```

Comment: I have tried modifying the code in both the ways you have mentioned but both of them are giving wrong answer for wt=[2,3,5,6,8,10] just like before and working for few other combinations.

Comment: @IPSITAMAZUMDER-110 Can you post your updated code and the failing testcase? For `n = 6, m = 10, wt = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10]` all three of the functions are returning `10` for me.